# git tag generated with ^{} at the end

Tags: git, tags, special-characters

I noticed that two tags were created with the same name (different commits) but one has `^{}` at the end of the name but is displayed without the `^{}`.

tags displayed using: `git show-ref --tags -d`

```
b26f55d refs/tags/TAG_NAME
73b49c5 refs/tags/TAG_NAME^{}
```

I have tried to recreate this type of tag, but haven't been successful.

Comment: `^{}` is the syntax to *dereference* a tag down to the commit it points to. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtemegemv0998em). If `73b49c5` is a commit, and `b26f55d` is a tag pointing to `73b49c5`, the expression `b26f55d^{}` will resolve to `73b49c5`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no two tags -- there is only one *tag* (with id `b26f55d`) pointing to the *commit* `73b49c5`. The second one is there due to the `-d` option whose doc says:

```
      -d, --dereference
           Dereference tags into object IDs as well. They will be shown with
           "^{}" appended.
```

A tag can be two things: A mere pointer to an object (usually a commit) XOR an object itself (i.e. with an id) *containing* a link to the tagged object. In this case the tag can contain additional information like signatures, comments, ...